# how to eager load count in eager loaded relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have many to many relation

```
Attendees belongsToMany ScheduledPrograms
Attendees belongsToMany ScheduledProgramSegments
```

I eager load the attendees  (appoligies for not cleaning out the extra code, i left it in case it's relevent)

**inside the controller**

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
    ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
    ->with(['attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }])
    ->with(['scheduledProgramSegments.attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }])
->get();


return View::make('admin/users/show',compact('programs');
```

**How do I also eager load the count of the attendees?**

---

### **Extra information**

I use an accessor to get the count in my view like so

**inside the model**

```
  public function getRegisteredCountAttribute()
  {
    return $this->attendees()->wherePivot('registered',1)->count();
  }
```

**View**

```
      <td>{{{$program->registeredCount}}}</td>  
      @foreach($program->scheduledProgramSegment as $program_seg)    
          <td>{{{$program_seg->registeredCount}}}</td>      
      ...
```

but this does a query each time so i have around 300 queries...

Comment: maybe you can solve it it via the "withCount" method.. to count it directly instead of each time in the view. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations (Counting Relationship Results)

Comment: @AlexMeyer Thanks! I added that to my controller query and it reduced my queries down to 65!

Comment: @AlexMeyer spoke too soon...it only reduced my queries because calling attendee_count in my view was broken...probably because I'm on 4.2 and withCount doesn't exist.

Comment: hm right added in 5.2.* dont remember exactly.. can you triy to call the pivot count with the property instead of function? $program_seg->attendees->wherePivot('registered',1)->count()

Comment: @AlexMeyer I can use $program_seg->attendees->wherePivot('registered',1)->count() directly in my view...if that's what you mean? If you mean can I put that into the controller where it gets eager loaded, that is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the controller

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
    ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
    ->with([
        'attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
        },
        'scheduledProgramSegments.registeredAttendees'=>function($q) {
            $q->wherePivot('registered', true);
        },
        'scheduledProgramSegments.attendees'=>function($q) use($user_id) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

inside the model (ProgramSegment model)

```
  public function registeredAttendees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attendees::class);
  }
```

View

```
{{ $program_seg->registeredAttendees->count() }}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to reduce the number of queries. It doesn't seem to be eager loading the counts.

Comment: @Phil I'm pretty sure it works. Maybe the problem lies on calling the with builder three times. I have fixed that, please try again. Do not forget to change the code in the controller, view and model.

Comment: Does the way you declare the relation in the model eager load the count? It still seems to do a new query each time *->count() is called even if the relation is eager loaded, count is not.

Comment: @Phil I get it. You need the attendees inside the scheduledProgramSegments, not the ScheduledProgram. Let me fix it again.